# What does, Must declare the scalar variable @vendor mean?

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I have read other posts and tried, changed and tried again only to be back to the code below.  I can't figure out why "@vendor" is not declared.  It must be something very simple and I have looked for so long that I just can't see it.

```
private string Get_Vendor_ID()
{
    string vendor_ID = "";
    string vendor = vendorTextBox.Text;
    string SQL = "SELECT Vendor_ID FROM Vendor WHERE Vendor_Name = @vendor";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL, DataAccessClass.sql_Connection);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_ID", vendor_ID);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendor_Name", vendor);
    DataAccessClass.OpenConnection();
    SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (sqlDataReader.Read())
    {
        vendor_ID = sqlDataReader["Vendor_ID"].ToString();
    }
    DataAccessClass.CloseConnection();
    return vendor_ID;
}
```

Any advise would be great.

Comment: Compiler? I think SQL engine would be the one complaining here.

Comment: What do you think you're doing here?  You have a parameter @vendor, but never defined it.

Comment: @GrantWinney: I didn't have that line originally and just forgot to remove it prior to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this specific line,

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_ID", vendor_ID);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vendor_Name", vendor);
```

There is no `@vendor` declaration

try changing it to.

```
string SQL = "SELECT Vendor_ID FROM Vendor WHERE Vendor_Name = @Vendor_Name";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help DevEstacion.  Wish I realized this a couple hours ago.